# OpenCV Mat::ones function

Tags: c++, opencv

According to the docs, this function should return a `Mat` with all elements as ones.

```
Mat m = Mat::ones(2, 2, CV_8UC3);
```

I was expecting to get a 2x2 matrix of `[1,1,1]`. Instead, I got this:

```
[1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0] [1, 0, 0]
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like `Mat::ones()` works as expected only for single channel arrays. For matrices with multiple channels `ones()` sets only the first channel to ones while the remaining channels are set to zeros.

Use the following constructor instead:

```
Mat m = Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(1,1,1));
std::cout << m;
```

**Edit**. Calling

```
Mat m = Mat::ones(2, 2, CV_8UC3);
```

is the same as calling

```
Mat m = Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC3, 1); // OpenCV replaces `1` with `Scalar(1,0,0)`
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. In my case, I had to do Scalar(255,255,255) instead (for type CV_8UC4)