# initializing 3 channel Mat with ones

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to initialize a 3 channel Mat with ones, but

```
Mat img_l=Mat::ones(2048,3072,CV_8UC3)
cout << (uint)img_l.at<Vec3b>(4,4)[0] << (uint)img_l.at<Vec3b>(4,4)[1] << (uint)img_l.at<Vec3b>(4,4)[2] << endl;
```

returns 1 0 0

How can I initialize G, B and R channels?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV Mat::ones function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469734/opencv-matones-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV cv::Mat 'ones' for multi-channel matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343662/opencv-cvmat-ones-for-multi-channel-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign Scalar to matrix, like this:

```
img_l=Scalar::all(1);
```

or

```
img_l=Scalar(1,1,1,1);
```